# iOS - Connect UILabel from interface builder to code

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to set a custom font on a UILabel, which I've figured out how to do just fine. My question is how do I access a UILabel that I created via the drag and drop interface builder in the code?

I've tried ctrl + clicking the UILabel and dragging it to the file's owner but it won't let me.  I also tried opening the assistant editor and connecting the UILabel directly to the corresponding .h file, but that won't work either. How do I access the UILabel programatically?? I know this should be really easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// YourController.h

@interface YourController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *theLabel; 
@end

// YourController.m

@implementation
@synthesize theLabel; 
///....
@end
```

Now with the `IBOutlet` marker in your code you should be able to drag **from File's Owner to the label** (not the other way round) in IB.

Comment: Great, thank you! One follow up question: I noticed that in some cases theLabel is declared in {curly brackets} even before the @property statement, like in Karoly's answer. What is the reason behind this? Is it required, best practice, other?

Comment: Not required. This also creates an local instance variable which is not necessary. In iOS 6 it will be even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you added the UILabel to your .xib file.  ctrl click the UILabel and dragged it to your .h file.  You will have to enter certain info including the name of the Label.  Use the name of the label that you entered from y our .m file to access it.

By ctrl+click and dragging the UILabel from the .xib to the .h, you will basically add the UILabel as a property.  It will automatically added implementation of it in the .m file so you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the UILabel at any point, you need to declare it in the .h file, and the .m file where you plan to modify it.

When you declare it is should like roughly like:

```
@interface MyObject { 

UILabel *_testLabel;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel
```

Then of course you would do,

```
@synthesize testObeject = _testLabel;
```

in your .m file. After you've done this, you can link the actual variable to your physical label in your .xib file the way you were attempting to before.